# How to specify the fromXType attribute in xml anim file

Tags: android, xml, animation

I want to make the same animation in xml as in code.
I code I have this

```
    Animation a = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT , 1.1f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -0.2f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
```

I start with this in my xml anim file but I do not know how to tall him that the translation should be relative to parent

```
<translate
    android:duration="2500"
    android:fromXDelta="-0.1"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="200"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

Namely I do not know how to specify the fromXType attribute

fromXType   Specifies how fromXValue should be interpreted. One of Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, or Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to use the **P** parameter  like this

```
android:fromXDelta="-0.1%p"
```

[read here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)

Comment: You need to use -1 to mean -1% when using %p. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html